# Bash - String comparison does not work

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to compare two variables in a .sh file but it never works ;-( 
How can I compare them?

```
curDate=2014-03-09
nextDate=2014-04-17

if [ “$nextDate” = “$curDate” ]; then
   echo $curDate = $nextDate
else
    echo $curDate != $nextDate
fi
```

Comment: The code works just as expected - for the case you provide it prints `2014-03-09 != 2014-04-17` and when I change the curDate to the same value as nextDate it prints: `2014-04-17 = 2014-04-1`. Also on ideone: http://ideone.com/FSFMof and http://ideone.com/Qu59WJ

Comment: Are you actually using Bash, or some other shell?  Do you have `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script?

Comment: Are the fancy quotes `“` and `”` actually in your script? They should be normal double quotes `"`.

Comment: I am using the Mac OSX terminal and the code does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that is supposed to be a string should better be quoted:

```
echo "$curDate != $nextDate"
```

instead of

```
$curDate != $nextDate
```

Consider quoting date assignments too.

Try running this:

```
var=asd das
for thing in $var; do
echo $thing
done
```

and then with `var="asd das"`

Asides from that - use `"` instead of `“` in `if [ “$nextDate” = “$curDate” ]; then`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. 
In Mac OSX this solution works:

```
#!/bin/bash
  a=2014-03-09
  b=2014-03-09
if [[ $a == $b ]] ; then
  echo Found.
else
  echo not found
fi
```

Comment: Your original code would work as well, if you used `"..."` instead of `“...”` to quote the parameter expansions.